# Modem and Router for DSL

Tags: modem

I have a DSL connection from O2(Telefonica) and use a Router that was given to me by the provider, but this cartoon made me wonder how do I actually connect to the internet at home. Don't people still use Modem (atleast indirectly) when they connect to the internet though not necessarily in the form of a dialup Modem like in those old days? Or is it that a WLAN Router completely replaced a modem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you have at home is not just a "router" but a "modem-router" since inside it has both a DSL modem and it's a router in the proper sense of a device that does network routing.

If you had just one single PC then you could have a normal modem (there still exist both with USB or Ethernet input) for your DSL since you wouldn't need it to make other operations (which eventually your computer would do)

So yes: people still use a lot of Modems (modulator-demodulator) but they are now hidden in boxes that do also other stuff (routing, wireless access point, file sharing and so on) and therefore are getting less known to the general public.

Comment: so I am right in believing that Modem is functionally not obsolete? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. You totally need it to "encode/decode" the information over a lot of media still widely in use (ie. DSL, Cable...)

Comment: so i guess the cartoon is too simplistic, after all its just a cartoon.